# Run & Build options disabled in XCode 6.2

Tags: xcode6

I have a project that it was working fine, but suddenly I can't build or run anymore, the options are disabled from the menu

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need go to `Product > Scheme > Manage schemes`. Then the corrupt scheme should be in red, remove it. Finally click on Autocreate Schemes Now button. More information [here](http://mathijskadijk.nl/post/14637472099/xcode-build-button-disabled)

Comment: I just had the same problem years later in Xcode 8.2.3 -- the scheme wasn't red, so no indication it was corrupt, but deleting and auto re-generating a new one fixed my project.